# Do I need Linux for UCB's SPICE(3)?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

I have been reading a SMPS book with many simulated examples. I want to recreate the sims in the book and follow along with the shown examples. The author states that he uses SPICE for all examples, which I hear was developed at UCB a few decades ago. I already had LTSpice on my PC, so I figured I'd just use it. Then, some circuit examples use components I cannot find in LTSpice (e.g. adders, gain blocks). It seemed like too much work to try and create circuits that are effectively the same in LTSpice (I'm not very skilled in LTSpice as it is). So I figured I'd search for UCB's SPICE.

I quickly find the UCB SPICE page, and after enough clicks I find a page with downloads for SPICE. I was expecting executables, but find files with ".tar.gz" and phrases like "SPICE for linux."

Is it the case that UCB's SPICE software is available only for linux? If not, could anyone currently using it guide me to place it on my windows machine, or have suggested alternatives? Would I be better off finding workarounds in LTSpice? Thanks for your help!

Comment: .tar.gz is just an archive format, similar to .zip or .7z. It's popular in the POSIX world for whatever reason, but there's nothing saying it couldn't contain a windows executable.

Comment: "It's popular in the POSIX world for whatever reason" – The tar format is standardized in POSIX, which explains its popularity in the POSIX world. The gzip format is specified in RFC 1952 and is royalty-free, neither of which (used to be) true for PKZIP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/). This is effectively the "successor" of Berkeley SPICE, supports Windows, and is still maintained. From what I understand it does include effectively the original SPICE components, and has had the plotting and other parts ported to work with modern Linux or Windows.

I think your only other good option is using an actual Linux install (either via a virtual machine or as a dual boot), though I would probably not resort to this unless you really want to run the original Berkely SPICE.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure which SPICE element the author was referring to when they said "gain blocks", but VCVS's are certainly available in LTSpice if you know what to look for:

[image]

Elements E, F, G, and H are the VCVS, CCCS, VCCS, and CCVS, respectively.

It's also not 100% clear what you mean by an adder (neither an "adder" nor a "gain block" was part of classic Berkeley SPICE), but you could likely reproduce it's behavior with series connected VCVS's or with the arbitrary behavioral source (B element).

The biggest differences between versions of SPICE (Berkeley SPICE, HSPICE, PSpice, LTSpice, ...) is usually in the syntax of equations used to define arbitrary controlled sources, and possibly in advanced transistor models that are probably only important to you if you work for TSMC or someplace creating libraries for other engineers to use.

If you're just defining circuits with linear relations between circuit variables (node voltages and branch currents) you shouldn't have much trouble switching between SPICE versions to follow along with your book.

Also note: you can use LTSpice in batch mode where you write the circuit netlist in a text editor and call SPICE as a command-line program. Using it this way it should be mostly compatible with Berkeley SPICE (especially if you stay away from non-linear controlled sources).

Comment: OP probably sees some custom made blocks, in which case it's a matter of either building them, yourself, or using some 3rd party library.